# Hide all the rows after displaying two rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide rows after displaying two rows.

```
  $(window).load(function () {
  $(".ThisClass> div").next().next().css('visibility','hidden');
  })
```

I am able to do it with above code but what I wish to do is hide ALL the rows after two rows. The  above code is working only when there are 3 rows.

Please suggest.

Comment: would you show your HTML & CSS code as well ?

Comment: I got my answer, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) function.

First target the second element with `.eq(1)` (zero based index) and the use `.nextAll()` to assign any css to the following siblings of the selected element:

```js
$('#hide').on('click', function() {
   $('#test > .inner').eq(1).nextAll().hide();
});
```

```css
#test {
  width:100%;
}
.inner {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div class="inner">test</div>
  <div class="inner">test</div>
  <div class="inner">test</div>
  <div class="inner">test</div>
  <div class="inner">test</div>
  <div class="inner">test</div>
  <div class="inner">test</div>
</div>
<button id="hide">Hide rows</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple using <kbd>**[slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)**</kbd> function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ThisClass> div").slice(2).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ThisClass">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [`:gt(index)` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".ThisClass > div:gt(1)").css("visibility", "hidden");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div class="ThisClass">
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>def</div>
    <div>ghi</div>
    <div>jkl</div>
    <div>mno</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your css selector and hide all the rows.

```js
function hiderows() {
  $('.ThisClass > div:nth-child(n+3)').hide();
}

function showrows() {
  $('.ThisClass > div').show();
}
```

```css
.ThisClass > div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ThisClass">
  <div>#1</div>
  <div>#2</div>
  <div>#3</div>
  <div>#4</div>
  <div>#5</div>
  <div>#6</div>
  <div>#7</div>
</div>

<button onclick="hiderows()">Hide rows</button>
<button onclick="showrows()">Show rows</button>
```

[Vanilla-JavaScript solution](https://jsfiddle.net/v57afo39/)

Comment: Native selectors should be fastest. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt using <kbd>**[each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**</kbd> function

```
    $(".ThisClass> div").each(function (i) {
        if (i <=1)
            return true; // Skip first two divs
        else
            $(this).hide();

    });
```